# Spring Boot Authorization Server giving Invalid Client Error for Client Credentials grant type with client secret basic auth method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I have Spring Boot Authorization Server (version 1.0.1) running. When I set the client authentication method as **client_secret_post** at the backend and send the following request via Postman, I'm getting the access token.

[image]

Edit: I'm also attaching the screenshot of MySQL database entry for this client to show that the client_authentication_method in this case is set to **client_secret_post**. The client_secret here is hashed using Bcrypt Password Encoder.

[image]

However, when I change the authentication method to **client_secret_basic** and send the following request via Postman, I'm getting **invalid_client** error.

[image]

[image]

Edit: I'm also attaching the screenshot of MySQL database entry for this client to show that the client_authentication_method is set to **client_secret_basic**. The client_secret here is hashed using Bcrypt Password Encoder.

[image]

I'm attaching the console output of HTTP request and error response for reference here.

[image]

Here are the necessary codes and configuration snippets:

RegisteredClientRepository implementation:

```
@Service
public class ClientService implements RegisteredClientRepository {

 private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

 @Autowired
 ClientRepository clientRepository;

 @Override
 public void save(RegisteredClient registeredClient) {
 }

 @Override
 public RegisteredClient findById(String id) {
    return this.clientRepository.findByClientId(id);
 }

 @Override
 public RegisteredClient findByClientId(String clientId) {
    return this.clientRepository.findByClientId(clientId);
 }

}
```

Authorization Server Configuraion:

```
@Configuration
public class AvocadoAuthorizationServerConfiguration {

@Autowired
CryptoUtils cryptoUtils;

@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer = new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer();
    http
        .apply(authorizationServerConfigurer)
        .and()
        .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder userPasswordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
}

@Bean 
public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, IOException {
    RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) cryptoUtils.getPublicKey();
    RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) cryptoUtils.getPrivateKey();
    RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
            .privateKey(privateKey)
            .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .build();
    JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
    return new ImmutableJWKSet<>(jwkSet);
}

@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    RSAPublicKey publicKey = null;
    try {
        publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) cryptoUtils.getPublicKey();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(publicKey).build();
}
}
```

As per my understanding, when we are using **client_secret_basic** as the client authentication method, we are supposed to send clientId and clientSecret in base64 encoded format in the Authorization header. Is this understanding correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You will get the `invalid_client` error if your `RegisteredClient` does not have `client_secret_basic` as an allowed `clientAuthenticationMethod`. Make sure you have both specified. For example, when using an in-memory client (for demonstration purposes):

```java
    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("messaging-client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                // **** Ensure both are allowed if both methods are needed
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
                // ****
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .authorizationGrantType(OAuth2DeviceCode.GRANT_TYPE)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc")
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .scope("message.read")
                .scope("message.write")
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();

        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }
```

---

If that does not solve your issue, please share your configuration.

Comment: Please see the edited question. I have attached MySQL DB entry screenshot to show that the client authentication method is correctly defined in the client repository. As per your suggestion, I even tried after adding both the client authentiation methods: client_secret_post and client_secret_basic. But that did not solved the issue. I'm only getting the access token in the case when I'm using client_secret_post method.

Comment: @AdityaKumar Sorry to hear that. Please enable trace logs with `logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace` and post the logs from the request.